# get facebook graph api response with google cloud functions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am currently developing an Android app that outputs the posts of a Facebook page.
Of course I want to notify the app users about new posts. Then I connected my app to Firebase Notification. When I enter and send a message there, a push message is displayed on the mobile phone. Of course I don't want to create the push message manually in Firebase every time there is a new post. So I thought I could create a function in Firebase cloud functions that gets the posts from Facebook Graph API, writes to the database and compares (Primary Key Facebook id) if there are new posts. I have searched Google for several hours, if there is a comparable topic already, but I havn't found anything. I have also worked through the documentation of Firebase cloud functions, but havn't found a starting point. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?